# In docker can't use tree command, get error: /bin/sh: 52: tree: not found

Tags: python, docker, tree, sh, bin

I'm using docker, I want to use `tree` command, but I get error:

```
# tree -L 1
/bin/sh: 52: tree: not found
# whereis tree
tree:
# apt install tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tree
# pip install tree
Requirement already satisfied: tree in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tree) (10.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: svgwrite in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tree) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tree) (57.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tree) (8.1.7)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
# tree -L 1
/bin/sh: 56: tree: not found
#
```

How should I do?

Comment: Docker images come without package database. So, do an `apt update` before any installation.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for your `apt update`. But I use `pip install tree` that successful install tree yet can't use tree, why?

Comment: you have to install it by `apt install tree`, it's not command by python what you want to use @KlausD.

Comment: @KlausD. Your solution is right, first run `apt update` then run `apt install tree`, that worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour When I first run `apt update` then run `apt install tree`, I found that I don't install `tree` by `apt install tree` before.

Answer (score 0):

According to solution that @Klaus D. give.

First run command:

```
apt update
```

then run command:

```
apt install tree
```

now can use `tree -L 1` command.